# Nested RecyclerViews : Cannot call notifyDataSetChanged() method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I have to do nested RecyclerView.
I have  a big list : **list_one**, which contains a title and another list, **list_two**, which contains a String and a CheckBox.

When setting up a **list_two**, if the String is selected (by default), I want to call the adapter of **list_one** to add an item, and call *notifyDataSetChanged()*.

But, when I do that, I get an exception :

```
Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling.
```

I think that it's because the **list_two** did not charged completely yet, so the size of **list_one** is not set correctly.

Is there a way to **wait until the list_two charged completely, to call *notifyDataSetChanged* in the first list ?**

Here is a picture to help you visualize the lists goal :
[image]

The **first_list** contains "Couleur", "Taille" and "Test".

The **second_list** of the **first_list** first item contains "Bleu", "Rouge" and "Vert" (pretty confusing, I know)

For example, if I select "Rouge", the **first_list** needs to refresh to add or delete some items that are not compatible with "Rouge".
That's why I need to do this trick.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Have you tryed with  

    list_one.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });